# Botão ao lado de text bar com Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou a tentar criar um formulário muito simples com o Bootstrap que consiste apenas numa *text bar* e num botão de procurar. Mas, embora estejam os dois no mesmo `.form-group`, a *text bar* tem uma `width` de 100% e o botão fica em baixo, em vez de aparecer ao lado, como eu precisava.

Está ai um exemplo:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="searchBar">Procurar:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" id="searchBar" placeholder="Procurar por:">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" value="Procurar"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackblather/Lq8Z4/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está usando o bootstrap 3, que é bem diferente do bootstrap 2. Estão faltando alguns elementos na sua estrutura de HTML. Veja o fiddle:

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq8Z4/5/)

HTML:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="searchBar">Procurar:</label>
        <div class="input-group"><!--Estava faltando essa div-->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchBar" placeholder="Procurar por:" />
            <span class="input-group-btn"><!--Estava faltando esse span-->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Procurar">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Veja mais sobre os [componentes do bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) na página oficial deles.

Comment: Obrigado, era mesmo isso que queria :)

Answer (score 0):

Mude a seguinte propriedade:

> De

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

> Para

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

[]'s

Answer (score -1):

Filipe.Fonseca respondeu, mas caso você queira fazer isso apenas para o campo em questão utilize direto no style do campo

```
`style="width:90%;"`
```

ou crie um novo estilo para esse campo

Comment: Criar um novo estilo seria realmente a solução para este campo em particular, mas como se trata sempre de um campo de busca, acho redundante. De qualquer maneira, alterar direto no style do campo _suja_ o código, não recomendo.

Comment: Ensinando hardcode style, coisa feia Renan...hahaha

Comment: forma mais simples de se entender rsrs